# Java: adding a menubar to borderlayout

Tags: java, swing

Can someone please tell me how I can add my menubar to the borderlayout NORTH.

I have written it this way.

```
     private void makeFrame()
    {
    frame = new JFrame("Game");

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);   
    contentPane.add(new JButton("south"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);      
    contentPane.add(new JButton("center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    contentPane.add(new JButton("east"), BorderLayout.EAST);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    makeMenuBar();
}


    public void makeMenuBar(){


       JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu menu; 
    JMenuItem item;


    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(file);

     item = new JMenuItem("New Game...");
    file.add(item);

    item = new JMenuItem("Save As...");
    file.add(item);

    item = new JMenuItem("Quit");
    file.add(item); 

    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to add this menubar to border north please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't, instead, you should use [`JFrame#setJMenuBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar)) instead

The problem you are having seems to be the fact that you are either adding the menu bar to the container BEFORE it's initialized or are creating a new instance of `JMenuBar` which is never added to the screen

```
private void makeFrame()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Game");

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // ?? Don't know what this initialised to...
    contentPane.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);   
    //...
    makeMenuBar();
}

public void makeMenuBar(){
   // A local variable with the same name...??
   JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
```

Oh, and the instance you are creating in `makeMenuBar` is only local to the method...so it will never have an effect on the `menubar` variable you are using in `makeFrame`...

Comment: I made the Menubar a field and it works! Thank you :)